# nestjs-swagger-dto - startTime is not ISO8601 format error

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-transformer, nestjs-swagger

I'm using the [`nestjs-swagger-dto`](https://github.com/glebbash/nestjs-swagger-dto) package and I'm getting the error `"startTime is not ISO8601 format."` I don't understand why, because the `startTime` property in the request body is a string in ISO8601 format.

Here is my MyDto class:

```
export class MyDto {
  @IsDate({
    nullable: true,
    format: 'date-time',
  })
  startTime: Date | null;
}
```

Here is my Post request body:
JSON

```
{
  "startTime": "2023-10-24T16:13:58.325035"
}
```

Here is my controller code:

```
@Post()
async create(@Body() dto: MyDto) {
  // ...
}
```

I have a global validation pipe in my main.ts file:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    forbidUnknownValues: true,
    transform: true,
  }),
);
```

I tried copying the `isDateString` function from the `nestjs-swagger-dto` package to my `MyDto.ts` file and adding some console logs before and inside the if statement:

```
if (!isDateString(value, { strict: true })) {
  // ...
}
```

Here is the output of the console logs:

```
// this is a string
2023-10-24T16:13:58.325035

// this is a date object
2023-10-24T14:13:58.325Z
```

It seems like the validation is correctly phrasing the string and after that it's trying to validate a date object, which was previously converted and this is of course not a string. This is why `isDateString` is failing.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my code, NestJS, or the nestjs-swagger-dto package. Can anyone help me here?

Thank you in advance